# using impersonate in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Can anyone explain to me how

```
  <identity impersonate="true" />
```

works?  I have created a web application that has a dialog that allows users to view folders on a server.  It works by using an update panel and refreshing the dialog treeview.  Essentially, what it does is get the parent node (which has the path to the server folder) and uses DirectoryInfo to get all its children.  Then, when a user clicks on a child, it gets refreshed with all of its children.  But, heres the problem.  If I have a path like this:

\myServer\

The user can navigate to

\myServer\someFolder\

Then

\myServer\someFolder\sharedFolderOnAnotherServer\

Then

\myServer\someFolder\sharedFolderOnAnotherServer\anotherFolder\

All is good.  But, if I start with

\myServer\someFolder\sharedFolderOnAnotherServer\

And try to move to a child, I get this error:

"the account used is a computer account.  Use your global user account or local user account to access this server."

As the path illustrates, the folder “sharedFolderOnAnotherServer” is actually a shortcut to a shared folder on another server.  If I start from the root then work my way to the final folder, it’s as if my permissions from the first server are carried over to the second server and everything is fine.  But, if I skip the first server, and go right to the second, I don’t carry over my permissions.  If I use the impersonate tag in my web.config file, it works fine but causes other problems with getting the current logged in user and using active directory.  Can anyone explain why I can’t jump right to the: \myServer\someFolder\sharedFolderOnAnotherServer\anotherFolder\ path without starting from the beginning and what impersonate does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without impersonation, the web server accesses resources using the identity of the application pool it is running under.  When you use impersonation, the web server accesses resources using the identity of the user that is authenticated - i.e your end user.  In other words, your web server process "impersonates" your end user.

Impersonate=true causes the web server to impersonate the end user for the entire request.  Another option, if you need finer grained control, is to use impersonation in your code:

```
//Request uses application pool identity out here.
WindowsIdentity identity = (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
if(identity != null)
{
    using(identity.Impersonate())
    {
        //Request uses end user identity to access resources here
    }
    //back to using application pool resources.
}
```

This assumes you are using Windows Authentication or some other form of authentication that sets HttpContext.Current.User to a WindowsPrincipal.